# Passing Data from TableViewCell labels to a ViewController

Tags: swift

Project: https://github.com/vpags1/events.git

I am needing to pass data from a TableView to a ViewController. The data is being displayed on a cell with two labels and UIIMage (name, details, photo) that when clicked brings you to the other detail view controller, which displays the information.

How I have it now, the data is stored in three arrays in the view controller, however when I talked to my professor he told me that the easiest way to do this would be to store the data in a separate file. I really have no idea how to achieve this, and would appreciate any help whether it is way or another method.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var names = ["Brown Diner", "Kirkland", "Choco", "Lil Wayne", "Annie", "Social"]
    var details = ["Free drink with meal after 12 AM", "LADIES drink free", "10% off all ice cream!", "concert", "a Theater Production", "Bring your Squad to the Social"]
    var images = [UIImage(named: "brown"), UIImage(named: "kirk"), UIImage(named: "choco"), UIImage(named: "lilwayne"), UIImage(named: "default"), UIImage(named: "default")]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.eventsTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    cell.name.text = names[indexPath.row]
    cell.detail.text = details[indexPath.row]
    cell.photo.image = images[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.names.count
    }
//    
//    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
//        
//        if segue.identifier == "detailsSegue" {
//            guard let eventVC = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailsViewController,
//                let eventIndex = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row else {
//                    return
//            }
//            eventVC.eventName = names[eventIndex]
//            eventVC.eventDetail = details[eventIndex]
//            eventVC.eventPhoto = images[eventIndex]
//        }
//        
//    }
}
```

my detailsViewController

```
import UIKit

class DetailsViewController : UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var detailsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var detailsImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var detailsDesc: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

    }
}
```

my CustomCell.swift file

```
import UIKit

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var photo: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var detail: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

I am very new to Swift, and it has proven to be very challenging for me. I'm really not a coder, however a project demands that I complete some of the coding for an application that I am the UI/UIX designer of. Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a JSON file with the data in your arrays and add it to your project:

```
{
    "events":[
              {
              "name": "BTown Diner",
              "details": "Free drink with meal after 12 AM",
              "image": "btown"
              },
              {
              "name": "Dunnkirk",
              "details": "LADIES drink free",
              "image": "dunn"
              },
              {
              "name": "Chocolate Mousse",
              "details": "10% off all ice cream!",
              "image": "choco"
              },
              {
              "name": "Lil Wayne",
              "details": "Lil 500 concert",
              "image": "lilwayne"
              },
              {
              "name": "Annie",
              "details": "an IU Theater Production",
              "image": "default"
              },
              {
              "name": "Campus Squad Social",
              "details": "Bring your Squad to the Campus Squad Social",
              "image": "default"
              },
              ]
}
```

Create an `Event` class to encapsulate the data for a single event:

```
import UIKit

class Event {

    let name: String!
    let details:String!
    let image: UIImage!

    init(eventData: [String: String])
    {
        self.name = eventData["name"]
        self.details = eventData["details"]
        self.image = UIImage(named: eventData["image"]!)
    }
}
```

Add a property of type Event to your DetailsViewController:

```
import UIKit

class DetailsViewController : UIViewController {

    // To get the event from the main view controller
    var event: Event!


    @IBOutlet var detailsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var detailsImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var detailsDesc: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        detailsLabel.text = event.name
        detailsDesc.text = event.details
        detailsImage.image = event.image
    }
}
```

Add an array of class event to your main ViewController
Read the JSON data in ViewDidLoad and populate your `events` array
Implement prepareForSegue and set the `event` property of DetailsViewController with the selected event.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    // Created an Event class to store the event data 
    // Moved the hard coded data to Events.json
    var events = [Event]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Read the JSON data from main bundle
        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Events", ofType: "json") {
            do {
                let jsonData = try NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe)
                let parsedData = parseJSON(jsonData); // parse data to Swift dictionary
                print(parsedData)
                if let result = parsedData.result where parsedData.error == nil {

                    if let eventsData = result["events"] as? [[String : String]]  {

                        for event in eventsData {

                            events.append(Event(eventData: event)) // Create an event from JSON data and add to the list
                        }
                    }

                }
            } catch {}
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return events.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        cell.name.text = events[indexPath.row].name
        cell.detail.text = events[indexPath.row].details
        cell.photo.image = events[indexPath.row].image

        return cell
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

                if segue.identifier == "detailsSegue" {
                    guard let eventVC = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailsViewController,
                        let eventIndex = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row else {
                            return
                    }
                    // set the event to detail view controller
                   eventVC.event = events[eventIndex]

                }
    }

    // Standard JSON parsing code
    func parseJSON(data: NSData) -> (result: [String : AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) {

        var parsingError: NSError? = nil
        let parsedResult: [String : AnyObject]?
        do {

            parsedResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? [String : AnyObject]
        } catch let error as NSError {

            parsingError = error
            parsedResult = nil
        }
        return (parsedResult, parsingError)
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: WOW yes thank you. Sorry, I am a noob... How do I create a JSON file?

Comment: I made a pull request with the changes to your GitHub  repo you mentioned above.. To create a JSON file in Xcode, File -> New -> Other -> Empty  and name the file Whateveryouwant.json

Comment: I know it took a while, but your answer was extremely helpful! I feel so close I can taste it, however, I keep receiving errors of an Unresolved Identifier "Event"... Would you have an idea how to fix this? @muneeb

Comment: Have you created the class Event as shown above in my answer? Also please check your GitHub repo, I have created a pull request with these changes, so if you accept and merge that pull request, you will have a working version to refer to.

Answer (score 0):

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    weak var superTableView: ViewController!
    .....
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.eventsTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.superTableView = self
}
```

now you can pass data to any properties of your ViewController

Comment: I`m not very clear of what you want to do with your DetailsViewController

Answer (score 0):

### Preparing the data

Your professor probably meant storing the data in another class / struct, e.g.:

```
struct Data {
    let name   : String
    let detail : String
    let image  : String
}
```

And you can use an array of this struct to populate your tableview: `let data = [Data]`.

It's pretty straight forward and you can access it similarly like you've done:

```
cell.name.text   = data[indexPath.row].name
cell.detail.text = data[indexPath.row].detail
cell.photo.image = UIImage(named: data[indexPath.row].image)
```

You could achieve the same result by using an array of an array (or a dictionary / tuple) as well:

```
let data = [["Brown Diner", "Free drink", "brown"], ["Kirkland", "Ladies drink", "kirk"]]

cell.name.text   = data[indexPath.row][0]
cell.detail.text = data[indexPath.row][1]
cell.photo.image = UIImage(named: data[indexPath.row][2])
```

### How to pass the data

Since you've already started using `prepareForSegue`, you could use the following to pass the data:

In `tableView(didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)` use the following to start the segue and pass the data as sender:

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("detailsSegue", sender: data[indexPath.row])
```

And in `prepareForSegue`:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "detailsSegue" {
        let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailsViewController

        controller.info = sender as? Data // controller.info is an optional here
    }
}
```

### How to create the array of Data

Continuing with what you have already, you could easily create the array like this:

```
let names   = ["Brown Diner", "Kirkland", "Choco"]
let details = ["Free drink", "Ladies free", "10% discount"]
let images  = ["brown", "kirk", "choco"] // Changed this to an array of type String

let data = zip(zip(names, details), images).map { Data(name: $0.0.0, detail: $0.0.1, image: $0.1) }
```